# "ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file dpm_orte.c at line 167" causes Fortran program utilizing OpenMPI to crash

Tags: fortran, mpi, ipc, openmpi

I am in the process of learning how to use OpenMPI and Fortran. By making use of the OpenMPI documentation, I have tried to create a simple client/server program. However, when I run it I get the following error from the client:

```
[Laptop:13402] [[54220,1],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file dpm_orte.c at line 167
[Laptop:13402] *** An error occurred in MPI_Comm_connect
[Laptop:13402] *** reported by process [3553361921,0]
[Laptop:13402] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[Laptop:13402] *** MPI_ERR_INTERN: internal error
[Laptop:13402] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[Laptop:13402] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
-------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code.. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
-------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpiexec detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:
  Process name: [[54220,1],0]
  Exit code:    17
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The code for the Server and Client can be seen below:

server.f90

```
program name
use mpi
implicit none

    ! type declaration statements
    INTEGER :: ierr, size, newcomm, loop, buf(255), status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
    CHARACTER(MPI_MAX_PORT_NAME) :: port_name

    ! executable statements
    call MPI_Init(ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierr)
    call MPI_Open_port(MPI_INFO_NULL, port_name, ierr)
    print *, "Port name is: ", port_name

    do while (.true.)
        call MPI_Comm_accept(port_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, newcomm, ierr)

        loop = 1
        do while (loop .eq. 1)
            call MPI_Recv(buf, 255, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, newcomm, status, ierr)
            print *, "Looping the loop."
            loop = 0

        enddo

        call MPI_Comm_free(newcomm, ierr)
        call MPI_Close_port(port_name, ierr)
        call MPI_Finalize(ierr)    

    enddo

end program name
```

client.f90

```
program name
use mpi
implicit none

    ! type declaration statements
    INTEGER :: ierr, buf(255), tag, newcomm
    CHARACTER(MPI_MAX_PORT_NAME) :: port_name
    LOGICAL :: done

    ! executable statements
    call MPI_Init(ierr)
    print *, "Please provide me with the port name: "
    read(*,*) port_name

    call MPI_Comm_connect(port_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, newcomm, ierr)

    done = .false.
    do while (.not. done)
        tag = 0
        call MPI_Send(buf, 255, MPI_INTEGER, 0, tag, newcomm, ierr)
        done = .true.
    enddo

    call MPI_Send(buf, 0, MPI_INTEGER, 0, 1, newcomm, ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_Disconnect(newcomm, ierr)
    call MPI_Finalize(ierr)

end program name
```

I use `mpif90 server.f90 -o server.out` and `mpif90 client.f90 -o client.out` to compile and `mpiexec -np 1 server.out` and `mpiexec -np 1 client.out` to run the programs. It is when providing the client with the port name (i.e. when I press enter after the `read`) that the error occurs.

`which dpm_orte.c` returns `dpm_orte.c not found`

I am running Linux and I installed OpenMPI 1.10.3-1 from the Arch Extra.

Comment: @d_1999, I moved the MPI_Finalize() and tried anyway, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a trivial Fortran input handling mistake and has nothing really to do with MPI (besides the error message that Open MPI outputs being completely incomprehensible). Just insert a line in `client.f90` to print the value of `port_name` right after reading it:

```
print *, "Please provide me with the port name: "
read(*,*) port_name
print *, port_name
```

With the actual port name being something like `2527592448.0;tcp://10.0.1.6,10.0.1.2,192.168.122.1,10.10.11.10:55837+2527592449.0;tcp://10.0.1.6,10.0.1.4,192.168.122.1,10.10.11.10::300` the output will be `2527592448.0`. The list directed input treats `;` as separator and stops reading after it, thus the port address passed to `MPI_COMM_CONNECT` is incomplete.

The solution is to replace `read(*,*) port_name` with

```
read(*,'(A)') port_name
```

Also, the loop in the server is badly written. You cannot call `MPI_FINALIZE` more than once. And closing the port is also a bad idea given that you are calling `MPI_COMM_ACCEPT` immediately after. The correct loop would be:

```
! executable statements
call MPI_Init(ierr)
call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierr)
call MPI_Open_port(MPI_INFO_NULL, port_name, ierr)
print *, "Port name is: ", port_name

do while (.true.)
   call MPI_Comm_accept(port_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, newcomm, ierr)

   loop = 1
   do while (loop .eq. 1)
      call MPI_Recv(buf, 255, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, newcomm, status, ierr)
      print *, "Looping the loop."
      loop = 0
   enddo

   call MPI_Comm_disconnect(newcomm, ierr)
   call MPI_Comm_free(newcomm, ierr)
enddo

call MPI_Close_port(port_name, ierr)
call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
```

Comment: thank you so much for the `read` clarification. As for the loop, I am aware that it is not good, but I got stuck on the other error and simply bothered not to do more. Again - thank you!